# JSNI methods do not get compiled or added to the resulting JavaScript apparently

Tags: java, gwt

I've used GWT before and did not have any problem with JSNI, but now for some reason in a new project I have.

After having this issue with a more complicated setup I tried to test it with this small setup (removed  a few things from onModuleLoad which definetely have nothing to do with this error):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        Window.alert("number:"+getint());
    }

    public native int getint(); /*-{
        return 25;
    }-*/;
```

The exact same thing happens, which happened with my more complicated setup.

Dev Mode starts fine, however, this happens when I open it in Chrome:

[image: error description]

Even though the method is right there (and Chromes source assistant even shows the connection):

[image: chrome screenshot]

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon (`;`) after `getint()`:

```
public native int getint(); /*-{
```

It **must not** be there.

Comment: Oh my god. Usually missing semicolons cause issues, and now this. I would have *never* thought this would be the cause. Thankyou, really.

Comment: That said, please avoid writing new JSNI. Use JsInterop where possible (nearly everywhere) - this is future proofed.